# Spark3.2 write parquet files in spark2.3.1 format

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, dremio, parquet-mr

Hello All I am experiencing new issue due to third party reader.
I have written parquet files thru spark 3.2 but these parquet files can't be read by Dremio 20.4 version. I want to know do we have any flag or any way in spark 3.2 version , we can write the parquet same format as spark 2.3.1 version. Please let me know if you need more information.

I researched the spark3.2 API but didn't get any flag which can easily write in spark 2.3.1 version . I have to either write parquet files manually which may need more reengineering.

Comment: What's the error while accessing parquet from Dremio?

Comment: Sometimes Dremio doesn’t return any result where as if I will query it through Dremio upper version it returns correct result . Another error is decode column error